# why do we have to fix the duration for each measurement iteration?

Tags: java, jmh

what does the timing for iterations means ?

```
@Measurement(iterations = 50, time = 2)
```

Should the time of the measurement be fixed, if an iteration of the measurement takes longer than 2 seconds, the iteration will be stopped ? If that is true what impact does this have on the measurements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straightforward answer to that question is: "We have to provide the iteration time (or rely on the default iteration time), because otherwise the iteration will never stop". Depending on benchmark mode, the meaning for iteration time may be different. For example, [Javadoc says](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/406b03c83e5e/jmh-core/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/annotations/Mode.java#l35):

```
/**
 * <p>Throughput: operations per unit of time.</p>
 *
 * <p>Runs by continuously calling {@link Benchmark} methods,
 * counting the total throughput over all worker threads. 
 * This mode is time-based, and it will run until the iteration
 * time expires.</p>
 */
Throughput("thrpt", "Throughput, ops/time"),
```

There is no way to stop uncooperative execution in Java, short of killing the VM. (Interrupting the thread needs cooperation: something there should check for interruption). Therefore, if `@Benchmark` call takes longer than requested iteration time, we have no other option except for waiting for it.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://java-performance.info/jmh/):

> Allows you to provide the actual test phase parameters. You can specify number of iterations, how long to run each iteration and number of test invocations in the iteration (usually used with @BenchmarkMode(Mode.SingleShotTime) to measure the cost of a group of operations – instead of using loops).

Comment: If you're going to quote the documentation, please make it clear that's what you're doing. (Not that I think it does enough to answer the question, on its own.)

Comment: Also, the java-performance.info is *NOT* an authoritative documentation source for JMH, and should be marked as such. Quoting Javadocs is fine as the "documentation".